# Display issues when logging in

Tags: boot, nvidia, dual-boot, 12.10

I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my PC  alongside Windows 7 option. All seemed to be working fine. I installed Chrome and FileZilla, installed updates which had downloaded during the install, rebooted, and I get the usual boot options (Launch Ubuntu, Ubuntu with Linux, Memory test, and boot Windows 7 on SDB1). Booting into Windows 7 is fine.
When I select 'Launch Ubuntu' it proceeds to the Unity Greeter.

However, when I enter my credentials, I then have display issues. The screen becomes smaller, leaving a black border around the screen, almost as if I'm using a lower resolution than my monitor allows, shows my desktop wallpaper, and does nothing. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> allows me to log off which I can then reboot from the top right, but that is all.

PC Specs:
Intel Core 2 Duo 2.7Ghz - 4GB RAM - nVidia GeForce GT 220 - 1TB WD Hard Drive(7200rpm)

These specs ran Windows 7 Ultimate fine, with all the Aero graphics, so that surely cannot be the issue.

Comment: Welcome on Ask Ubuntu, Scott Thornton ! If you type Ctrl+Alt+F1, do you go to the command line ? If yes this will be useful to give you an answer. Ctrl+Alt+F7 should bring you back to the Graphical User Interface.

Comment: @Agmenor It launches the command line when prompted, also, pressing alt + F10, takes me to the setting screen, had a little look around in there, and its telling me my Acer 22" external monitor is a laptop monitor, and it is not picking up my graphics card, resolution will not go any higher than 1280 x 1024, although my monitor support 1920 x 1080, this explains the black border. Its almost as if im logging in, but not been shown my toolbar, applications or anything similar.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are actually logging in but you cannot see the panel bar and the launcher bar. If this is the case, try the following:

- Hit the Super key (Windows key), wait for a second, type "Software Sources", wait for a few seconds, then hit enter.
- The Software Sources app should pop-up in the middle of your screen, so you should be able to see it. Click on the "Additional drivers" tab.
- Follow the displayed instructions to install the best driver for your hardware.